# Access environment variables in Meteor/React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am building a Meteor app with a React front end. I am wanting to set environment variables on the server for link URLs, that way these URLs can just be updated without a code change.

I tried creating a settings.json file, however you cannot access `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` from inside that. Is there a way to export something server side that I can pull in to the client to access the environment variables?

What is best practice on this (as I am fairly new to the meteor world)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to change the URLs frequently I would suggest to create new collection and store those URLs inside that collection. On the bonus side you will get reactive data source and "fail-safe" URL edits.

Comment: @erichardson30 by the way, I know for sure that in one of my projects I used METEOR_SETTINGS as env variable on server https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#METEOR-SETTINGS
Which sounds pretty good, since you will have normal way to access meteor settings and you will get your env variable stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of settings.json files for different environments. They are very handy, since you can pass them to the command-line, and they work well with deployment mechanisms such as meteor-up and galaxy.
A very well explained article can be found here: [making-use-of-settings-json](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/making-use-of-settings-json)

I would advise against using environment variables, which are subject to change. For that purpose, you should build yourself an external datasource/service or just build yourself a simple administration page.

Comment: This is essentially being hosted on aws and I'm looking to set env variables on the server itself and access those on the front end. That way when the URLs need to be updated, anyone could go into the server and update the values there without having to touch any code or files that are deployed (since it's being built/deployed with docker)

Comment: I can respect the fact you want to change settings without touching the code, but if you're willing to let people mess around with your server machine, you're begging for problems. I gave my two cents, feel free to do it your own way.

Comment: I appreciate it but it's a requirement. The business doesn't want to pay for a code change to update a link URL if it changes